# Pattern for a list that can contain two types of items

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, covariance, backwards-compatibility

I'm trying to figure out a nice way to adopt an API change we've recently undergone that "weakens" a type on one of our objects.

Users used to be able to provide a list of references to "Dogs". We've made a decision that we now accept "Dogs" and "Cats".

The client library uses strongly typed references, so the property currently looks like:

```
public List<IReference<Dog>> occupants { get; set; }
```

I considered changing it to:

```
public List<IReference<Animal>> occupants { get; set; }
```

But I don't like that what used to be compile-time validation is now run-time (and server-side) validation. I would have preferred to have something more strongly typed like:

```
public List<Occupant> occupants { get; set; }

public class Occupant : IReference<Animal> {
    IReference<Animal> _internalReference;
    public Occupant(IReference<Dog> dog) { _internalReference = dog }
    public Occupant(IReference<Cat> cat) { _internalReference = cat }
    //... (Implement IReference<Animal> as a pass-through to _internalReference)
}
```

Unfortunately, because C# does not allow implicit operators to convert from an interface, existing users updating their client library would have to undergo hundreds of lines of code changes to "wrap" all their existing `Dog` references in an `Occupant` constructor.

So next I considered creating a new class for the list with some helper methods:

```
public class OccupantList : List<Occupant> { 
    public void Add(IReference<Dog> newDog) => base.Add(new Occupant(newDog));
    public void Add(IReference<Cat> newCat) => base.Add(new Occupant(newCat));
    // For backwards compatibility with new list assignments
    public static implicit operator OccupantList(List<IReference<Dog>> legacy) =>
        new OccupantList(legacy.Select(dog => new Occupant(dog)));
}
```

Unfortunately, C# exposes no way to override the core `ICollection.Add` implementation behind the scenes, which is used by all sorts of reflection utilities and my JSON serializer to populate this list, so it complains when it's given objects to add that aren't already of the type `Occupant`. I personally encountered issues with the JSON deserializer I was using. I could write a custom deserializer for this class but I took it as a sign that trying to inherit `List<Occupant>` and add support for types that don't inherit from `Occupant` was a bad idea doomed for failure.

Does anyone have any ideas or examples that can might steer us in the right direction?

---

**This is only "my problem"**

The real kicker is that this isn't even a backwards incompatibility at the API layer. The API uses dynamic typing (JSON with a Python interpreter) so the only change is that the following JSON:

```
{ "occupants": [{"ref_id":"abc123"}, {"ref_id":"zzz999"}] }
```

becomes:

```
{ "occupants": [{"ref_id":"abc123", "ref_type": "Dog"}, {"ref_id":"gdr736", "ref_type":"Cat"}] }
```

With a backwards-compatibility rules that treats the reference as a "Dog" if no type is specified.

Unfortunately, because I made the early decision to add compile-time typing to these reference objects, the C# client library users are the only ones suffering from the type weakening, whereas the API is still able to figure out the appropriate type dynamically at runtime.

Comment: Another (breaking) change would be to change the `set` accessor to `private` (for `occupants`) and then provide `Add(Dog dog)` and `Add(Cat cat)` methods (instead of just `occupants.Add`). Haven't really thought this through, just a brainstorm idea...

Answer (score 2):

#### At worst:

You're going to hate this but if that API has any consumers the best practice suggests that your breaking changes means it's now time to version your API.

#### At best:

I don't see the signature of your API controller mentioned but if the model in question is defined as a parameter of that method you *might* be able to get away with overloading the controller method, letting the model binder handle the different shape, and then resolving the problem in some kind of middleware or automapper.

#### Why not solve with a change in the model?

Because it sounds like you've already released this API for some kind of external consumption you really *really* shouldn't break the contract described by that input model.

Comment: This is an interesting point. The API itself isn't backwards incompatible because it is dynamically typed (using JSON). I've updated my request with some of the details on this. Basically, it's "only my problem", API users doing direct JSON communication won't notice the change.